# about display android webpage after downloaded the .epub book

Tags: android

sir alread i downloaded .epub book through URL in that book 2 html pages are there my question is how to open that html page after downloaded .epub book in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use webview and give webview1.loadurl("path of that html page");